# Isotape responsive layout with toggles and unknown heights

Tags: responsive-design, grid, jquery-isotope, masonry

I am trying to create a masonary style layout using isotope. The layout must be a responsive grid with flexible columns. However each grid item has an hidden text element which opens when the image is clicked. This text will come from wordpress and therefore as an unknown length. I am trying to use the

```
.isotope("reLayout");
```

function to reset the layout when the item is toggled however it does not work. If you alter the size of the browser when the text is visible you can see that that the isotope layout kicks back in and gives the desired effect.

I have created a codepen to illustrate my issue. Any help would be appreciated

http://codepen.io/GlynnJohnson/pen/bLBCJ

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need top use:

```
$container.isotope("layout");
```

Not

```
$container.isotope("reLayout");
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/jaqvn)